# Java Bounded Type Parameter in Enum

Tags: java

I am trying to create following enum.

```
public enum MyEnum{
     LEAD {
       @Override 
       public boolean isValid(Lead lead) { //compile error, asks to retain type as T
       }
     },
     TASK {
       @Override 
       public boolean isValid(Task task) { //compile error, asks to retain type as T
       }
     };

     public abstract <T extends SObject> boolean isValid(T  object);
}
```

`Lead` and `Task` classes both extend `SObject`. My intention is to basically let clients be able to use `MyEnum.LEAD.isValid(lead)` or `MyEnum.TASK.isValid(task)`. Compiler shouldn't allow to pass other types.

Could someone help in understand why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Does Lead and Task have a common interface?  If not you will need to define the method with the type Object.

Comment: @JustinKSU, They both extend `SObject`.

Comment: Why use the `enum` for that call pattern?  Why not just add a static method on `Task` and `Lead` like `Lead.isValid(lead)`?  Or even non-static, and just call `lead.isValid()`?

Comment: Why have an abstract version of `isValid`, if you don't want any of the subclasses to define it for arbitrary `SObject`s?

Comment: @IanMcLaird, I can not modify those classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the generic method with the same generic method. If you want to do what you are asking you need a generic *class* - which an `enum` cannot be.

The point being that I refer to the `enum` by the class reference - i.e.

```
final MyEnum myenum = MyEnum.LEAD;
```

Now if I call `myenum.isValid()` I should be able to call it with *any* `SObject` as defined by your `abstract` method.
The generic method definition that you have doesn't actually do anything. All it is doing is capturing the type of the passed in `SObject` and storing it as `T`. A generic method is commonly used to tie together types of parameters, for example

```
<T> void compare(Collection<T> coll, Comparator<T> comparator);
```

Here we do not care what `T` actually is - all we require is that the `Comparator` can compare the things that are in the `Collection`.

What you are thinking of is a generic class, something like:

```
interface MyIface<T> {
    boolean isValid(T  object);
}
```

And then

```
class LeadValid implements MyIface<Lead> {
    public boolean isValid(Lead object){}
}
```

You see the difference is that you would have a `MyIface<Lead>` - you would have to declare the *type* of `MyIface`. In the `enum` case you only have a `MyEnum`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation of why it's not working. I had those generic classes in mind but wanted to avoid creating extra classes and thought  of using my existing enum for that.